# Как на питоне запустить в несколько потоков вызов функции и моментально получить результат первой ответившей?

Tags: python, многопоточность, распараллеливание

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


def foo(a):
    time.sleep(a)
    return a


def calc():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500) as pool:
        results = [pool.submit(foo, 1), pool.submit(foo, 10)]

        for future in as_completed(results):
            return future.result()


print(calc())
```

В данном коде в пул помещаю два вызова функции foo, которые в качестве параметра получают кол-во секунд, сколько им надо спать.

Данный код выведет на экран `1`, как результат самой первой выполнившейся функции.

Но проблема в том, что этот результат мы получаем только после 10 секунд, пока выполнится и вторая функция.

Как мне сделать такой функционал: все вызыва функций в этом пуле должны выполнять до конца, но как только мы получили хоть один ответ, то функция `calc` должна моментально завершиться, не ожидая завершения всех вызывов в пуле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` инструкция убирает за `ThreadPoolExecutor`: вызывает на выходе `pool.shutdown(wait=True)`. Она не может вернуться пока задачи в пуле выполняются.

Чтобы это поправить, нужно заменить `return` на `yield` and использовать `print(next(calc()))`.

Если последующие результаты не нужны, то необходимо предусмотреть возможность отмены уже запущенных задач.

*Очевидный* код с `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` не заработал (см. код в конце вопроса). Вот похожий пример c `multiprocessing` `ThreadPool`, который работает:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

@contextlib.contextmanager
def logged(message):
    logging.info('before {}'.format(message))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logging.info('after {}'.format(message))

def foo(a):
    with logged('sleep'):
        time.sleep(a)
    return a

def calc():
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(foo, [10, 1]):
            with logged('result'):
                yield result

logging.basicConfig(format="%(relativeCreated)5d %(threadName)s %(message)s",
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
with logged('calc'):
    print(next(calc()), flush=True)
```

#### Результат

```
    4 MainThread before calc
    8 Thread-2 before sleep
    8 Thread-1 before sleep
 1010 Thread-1 after sleep
 1010 MainThread before result
 1010 MainThread after result
1
 1109 MainThread after calc
```

Единичка показана после одной секунды. Последующие задачи отменены.

---

**Нерабочий** код с `concurrent.futures` пулом:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import logging
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool, as_completed

@contextlib.contextmanager
def logged(message):
    logging.info('before {}'.format(message))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logging.info('after {}'.format(message))

def foo(a):
    with logged('sleep'):
        time.sleep(a)
    return a

def calc():
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        for future in as_completed(pool.submit(foo, i) for i in [10, 1]):
            with logged('result'):
                yield future.result()


logging.basicConfig(format="%(relativeCreated)5d %(threadName)s %(message)s",
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
with logged('calc'):
    print(next(calc()), flush=True)
```

#### Результат

```
   43 MainThread before calc
   43 Thread-1 before sleep
   44 Thread-2 before sleep
 1045 Thread-2 after sleep
 1045 MainThread before result
 1046 MainThread after result
10053 Thread-1 after sleep
1
10054 MainThread after calc
```

Единичка показана только после 10 секунд.

Вариант с `multiprocessing` `ThreadPool` работает в этом случае даже если использовать `return`. `with` инструкция вызывает на выходе `pool.terminate()` в данном случае:

```
#!/urs/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

@contextlib.contextmanager
def logged(message):
    logging.info('before {}'.format(message))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logging.info('after {}'.format(message))

def foo(a):
    with logged('sleep'):
        time.sleep(a)
    return a

def calc():
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(foo, [10, 1]):
            with logged('result'):
                return result

logging.basicConfig(format="%(relativeCreated)5d %(threadName)s %(message)s",
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
with logged('calc'):
    print(calc(), flush=True)
```

#### Результат

```
   10 MainThread before calc
   13 Thread-2 before sleep
   13 Thread-1 before sleep
 1014 Thread-1 after sleep
 1014 MainThread before result
 1015 MainThread after result
1
 1114 MainThread after calc
```

Единичка показана после одной секунды.