# Как я могу завершить все потоки, в одном из них

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которая ищет строку в файле. Что бы было побыстрее я добавил многопоточность. Но появилась другая проблема. Как только один из потоков находил нужную строку - он отключался, но остальные продолжали поиски, ибо один поток = одна строка. Как я могу отключить скрипт, либо завершить все потоки?

П.С. raise SystemExit, break пробовал

Comment: есть куча вариантов: 1- daemon=True + exit main thread 2- `os._exit()` 3- thread pool .close and/or terminate 3- простой [флаг found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979760/4279) или stopped = threading.Event(): while not stopped.wait(interval): # next line, etc в зависимости как у вас код организован¶ Сомневаюсь без измерений или больше подробностей, что чтение файла быстрее стало при использовании нескольких потоков (это может быть, если файл уже в кэше)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как остановить сервер Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512897/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Таймер в Python: выйти из программы если пользователь не предоставил ввод за указанное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694130/23044)

Comment: похожий вопрос [Как на питоне запустить в несколько потоков вызов функции и моментально получить результат первой ответившей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445549/23044)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, решил сделать queue Fifo

Comment: pool как раз на основе очередей реализован, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874484/4279)¶ Стоит повториться, что [результаты при параллельном чтении сильно зависят в кэше файл или нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606833/fastest-way-to-sum-integers-in-text-file#comment40064167_25606833). Попытка читать параллельно может замедлить программу (лишние seek).

Comment: @jfs, а обычное os._exit(), не вызовет ошибок системы, памяти и т.д.?

Comment: вызов прекращает работу процесса . Эффект  от завершения процесса в любой момент зависит от процесса